# nxt for ROS hydro

Tags: moveit, nxt, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any chance there is support for the NXT on hydro. Or a .URDF for MoveIt. I know there are people that have used NXT in MoveIt but there is little support that I can find. Does anyone have any examples?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113386/nxt-for-ros-hydro/) by [drews256](https://answers.ros.org/users/10271/drews256/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have stared making an attempt at https://github.com/chalko/ros-nxt/tree/catkinize  However I am completly new to ROS.  Any help would be appreciated.  Or any pointers to others work.

I have made some progress on this
set your .rosinstall to

```
- git: {local-name: nxt_python, uri: 'https://github.com/chalko/nxt-python.git'} 
- git: {local-name: nxt, uri: 'https://github.com/chalko/ros-nxt.git'}
```

then

```
catkin_make
```

And you will at least be able to run

```
rosrun nxt_python nxt_test
```

which on my machine says

```
NXT brick name: Nick-NX 
Host address: 00:16:53:13:8C:D3 
Bluetooth signal strength: 0 
Free user flash: 61688 
Protocol version 1.124 
Firmware version 1.31 
Battery level 7422 mV
```

---

Originally posted by [Nick J Chalko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1591/nick-j-chalko/) with karma: 81 on 2013-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick J Chalko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1591/nick-j-chalko/) on 2014-01-08**:
I have made some progress on this
set your .rosinstall to
cat .rosinstall

- git: {local-name: nxt_python, uri: [https://github.com/chalko/nxt-python.git'}](https://github.com/chalko/nxt-python.git%27%7D)
- git: {local-name: nxt, uri: 'https://github.com/chalko/ros-nxt.git'}

then catkin_make

And you will at least be able to run
rosrun nxt_python nxt_test

which on my machine says

NXT brick name: Nick-NX
Host address: 00:16:53:13:8C:D3
Bluetooth signal strength: 0
Free user flash: 61688
Protocol version 1.124
Firmware version 1.31
Battery level 7422 mV

**Comment by [mdtobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5215/mdtobi/) on 2014-01-10**:
@nick-j-chalko: I've also catkinized the nxt-package (https://github.com/ToPitz/nxt_ros_catkin). Currently I'm testing and migrating the package to nxt_python 2.2 - Perhaps we could help each other...
@drews256: Have you tried the catkinized package under hydro?

**Comment by [Nick J Chalko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1591/nick-j-chalko/) on 2014-01-17**:
@mdtobi, that is great.  Yes I am using hydro.
So what have you got to work so far?

**Comment by [Torpeddo](https://answers.ros.org/users/12486/torpeddo/) on 2014-02-26**:
Hello, I'm sorry and maybe I'm totally stupid, but I have problem with this command:

- git: {local-name: nxt_python, uri: [https://github.com/chalko/nxt-python.git'}](https://github.com/chalko/nxt-python.git%27%7D)

Should I put the command to terminal exactly like above ?
If I do that, I'm getting: -: command not found .

Or how to set .rosinstall ??

I have a hydro on Ubuntu 13.04.
THX!

**Comment by [zior89](https://answers.ros.org/users/13176/zior89/) on 2014-03-12**:
hello, i am working with nxt too but with electric version. I am thinking in change to nxt_ros_catkin that you are speaking. Do you try this version? (https://github.com/ToPitz/nxt_ros_catkin). IN what ubuntu version and ros version are you working?

thanks million!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that there's several people working on EV3 support.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1